# How can I repackage my automated testing EXE as a series of unit tests in MSTest?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I have an automated testing application that runs as a console application (EXE). It looks in a specific folder for files containing test data, and runs a test for each of those files, writing the results to the console. Thus the number of tests actually run depends on the number of files in the folder.

I would prefer to have each test run as a unit test in MSTest so that I get the benefit of surfacing the results via the standard MSTest mechanism. However, while I can see how to create a *single* unit test that essentially does what the Main method of my console app does, I can't see how to make each test case (each file) show up as a separate test.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work - sort of - by using a data-driven test using the DataSource attribute and specifying a CSV data source. I created the CSV data source as a post-build step so that it contained the dynamic data I needed. Yuk!

However, I then abandoned MSTest altogether, and used Xunit. This is so much nicer, because it supports not only parameterized tests and tests whose test data are provided via a file or database, but also (via extensions) tests whose test data is provided by a class property - which was perfect for my needs.

Crucially, there's also an Xunit test runner for VS and MSBuild, etc. so it can be used with the standard testing framework.